# What color is a crewed vehicle?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In Magic the Gathering, most vehicles in the Kaladesh set appear to be colorless. If you crew with a green creature does the vehicle become green?

This would affect cards that target color.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the vehicle remains colorless but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, vehicles don't gain a color, they stay colorless. I suppose that'd make some sense thematically, but in terms of the rules, Crew is just an ability that turns a noncreature vehicle into a creature, and that's really all it does. You shouldn't really think of vehicles as having creature(s) inside them; they stay separate. It's more like the creature(s) cranking the engine starter.

You can see this from the full rules definition of crew (rule 702.121), which is conveniently quoted in the [Kaladesh Release Notes](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/kaladesh-release-notes-2016-09-16):

> 702.121a Crew is an activated ability of Vehicle cards. “Crew N” means “Tap any number of untapped creatures you control with total power N or greater: This permanent becomes an artifact creature until end of turn.”

Nothing in there about color!

The release notes also include rulings for a bunch of common (and less common) scenarios, the same ones that are reproduced in the Gatherer rulings for each vehicle - see for example [Fleetwheel Cruiser](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFleetwheel%20Cruiser%5d).

(And it's not just most - all vehicles are colorless artifacts.)